# LIKE clause issue in c# but works in SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I was having this issue of my comboBox value not returning the results I wanted based on a project I was working on.

So the issue is this: I want to search by way of a substring in the comboBox. To clarify,I want a string from the comboBox to return the necessary value based on any part of the string I entered. Currently all it does is populate the comboBox with the items. What I want is after populating the comboBox it should return a string based on any character I type in. So let's say I have the word "stack123" when I type "123" or "k" or any substring, it will narrow the comboBox items and show the values based on the substring entered or just return the word "stack123"

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%" + comboBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'; ";
```

And I don't know if this helps but this is the full thing:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace comboBoxTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillCari();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void fillCari()//fill Cari-med dropdown with values
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Carimed_Inventory;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con2.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%" + comboBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'; "; 
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("Item_Description"));
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des);
                }

                con2.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You've acknowledged your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and say it's just a practice exercise. But you should really learn to always write parameterized code. Why would you practice wrongly? You should also properly handle your `IDisposable` objects like `SqlConnection`. It should be wrapped in a `using` statement or disposed in a `finally` block.

Comment: Can it be due to case sensitivity?

Comment: It's bad practice to use `SELECT *` when you're only accessing one column from the result

Comment: @wdosanjos case sensitivity in what way?

Comment: The c# side is kinda moot here; what happens in SSMS?

Comment: @Jevon SQL Server can be configured for case sensitive or case insensitive (plus lots of other complex stuff); if the actual value is `'fooFlOwBar'`, then whether `table.column LIKE '%flow%'` matches or not depends on the case sensitivity setting

Comment: I agree with @mason. There is no excuse to not write proper code. We are not being picky. There is actually a chance your issue might go away by simply using parameterized queries.

Comment: As others have said, if you know this is a bad way to do it, why keep doing it? If your practice exercises aren't things you'd ever do for real, they're not much help as practice.

Comment: @MarcGravell I ran he query in SSMS by using a combination of two characters:
`SELECT * FROM Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%gh%'`

and it would return everything that contains "gh"

Comment: @Jevon k; and in your code / application version, does searching `gh` behave as expected and show those same results?

Comment: @MarcGravell in this case no it just loads the comboBox list and doesnt take the user input based on the query that is mentioned above. It only returns the necessary results based on letters being typed in order

Comment: You call this _fillCari_ in your form constructor. What is the initial value of this combobox1? At this point in time you have no chance to write something in that combobox, so the value used (if any) is something that you have set inside the InitializeComponent call. And why you set the items of the same combobox used for the search?

Comment: @mason ok you have  a point. Understood

Comment: @Juan I see your point but I highly doubt the issue will go away with it being parameterized

Comment: I think @Steve identified the problem. At the time you call `fillCari` the combo box is empty, so the criteria is `LIKE '%%'` which matches all records.

Comment: @Steve initially the value is that of what is being returned from the database using `SELECT` . Is it that it can't be used that way? Is it that I have to have  a separate function populate it first and then write a separate LIKE query?

Comment: Not necessarily, but at least you need to recall the fillCari, AFTER you have typed the new partial string. (In any case, I would find this pretty confusing from an user experience point of view)

Comment: @Steve actually attempted that through debugging already but it was the same result

Comment: Can you print the result of `string query` before you execute it? I'm curious to see what it's like. Have you tried using the SQL Profiler to see what's actually being sent to the SQL Server?

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue? When all else fails, it's worth trying things even if you think they won't make a difference. Did you try with a parameterized query? Also, please provide the actual value of the variable "query" after your concatenation. Is it throwing any errors? Do you see any results or is it returning an empty recordset? Did you make sure what you typed actually exists?

Comment: Yes I adjusted my code on my side to facilitate parameterized queries. As for if the value exists, yes it does, keep in mind it is pulling from the comboBox that is coming from the database so the values are present, just not working as desired. @Juan

Comment: Kewl.  Please provide the actual value of the variable "query" after your concatenation.

Comment: @Jevon The question needs more clarification. You need to say what happens exactly when you execute your code, currently you said *not returning the results I wanted*, It's not a suitable problem  description. You should describe what exactly you execute and what you get and what you expect. Currently, you are trying to load items based on `Text` of `comboBox1` and then you try to add loaded item to the same `comboBox1`! Why?! Also current code just loads all available *Carimeds* to combo box, because when you run the code `comboBox1.Text` is empty.

Comment: @RezaAghaei description updated

Comment: @RezaAghaei still not clear?

Comment: It's clear now that you want to have an autocomplete textbox/combobox which uses contains instead of startswith. The solution which you are trying to implement will not help you to gain what you want.

Comment: I realized autocomplete is not practical cause if it is a case of showing the like values in the list based on what is entered. It has to be strictly a drowdown of values @RezaAghaei

Comment: I found a work around by using the guide of this user from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/631196/combobox-with-suggest-ability-based-on-substring-s)
What was done by the author was that of overriding the default combobox setting in winforms. I just found a way to tie it into my code and got it up and running. Hopefully this is of help to someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround was using the guide of this user from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/631196/combobox-with-suggest-ability-based-on-substring-s).
What was done by the author was that of overriding the default combobox setting in winforms. I just found a way to tie it into my code and got it up and running. I will outline how it works

```
suggestComboBox.DataSource = new List<person>();
suggestComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

// then you have to set the PropertySelector like this:
suggestComboBox.PropertySelector = collection => collection.Cast<person>      
().Select(p => p.Name);

// the class Person looks something like this:
class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  public int Height { get; set; }
}</person>
```

And this is the Custom comboBox implementation:

```
public class SuggestComboBox : ComboBox
{
  #region fields and properties

private readonly ListBox _suggLb = new ListBox { Visible = false, TabStop = false };
private readonly BindingList<string> _suggBindingList = new BindingList<string>();
private Expression<Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>>> _propertySelector;
private Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>> _propertySelectorCompiled;
private Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> _filterRule;
private Func<string, bool> _filterRuleCompiled;
private Expression<Func<string, string>> _suggestListOrderRule;
private Func<string, string> _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled;

public int SuggestBoxHeight
{
    get { return _suggLb.Height; }
    set { if (value > 0) _suggLb.Height = value; }
}
/// <summary>
/// If the item-type of the ComboBox is not string,
/// you can set here which property should be used
/// </summary>
public Expression<Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>>> PropertySelector
{
    get { return _propertySelector; }
set
{
    if (value == null) return;
    _propertySelector = value;
    _propertySelectorCompiled = value.Compile();
}
}

///<summary>
/// Lambda-Expression to determine the suggested items
/// (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
/// <para>default: case-insensitive contains search</para>
/// <para>1st string: list item</para>
/// <para>2nd string: typed text</para>
///</summary>
public Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> FilterRule
{
    get { return _filterRule; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        _filterRule = value;
        _filterRuleCompiled = item => value.Compile()(item, Text);
    }
}

///<summary>
/// Lambda-Expression to order the suggested items
/// (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
/// <para>default: alphabetic ordering</para>
///</summary>
public Expression<Func<string, string>> SuggestListOrderRule
{
    get { return _suggestListOrderRule; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        _suggestListOrderRule = value;
        _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = value.Compile();
    }
}

#endregion

/// <summary>
/// ctor
/// </summary>
public SuggestComboBox()
{
    // set the standard rules:
    _filterRuleCompiled = s => s.ToLower().Contains(Text.Trim().ToLower());
    _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = s => s;
    _propertySelectorCompiled = collection => collection.Cast<string>();

    _suggLb.DataSource = _suggBindingList;
    _suggLb.Click += SuggLbOnClick;

    ParentChanged += OnParentChanged;
}

/// <summary>
/// the magic happens here ;-)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);

    if (!Focused) return;

    _suggBindingList.Clear();
    _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
    _propertySelectorCompiled(Items)
         .Where(_filterRuleCompiled)
         .OrderBy(_suggestListOrderRuleCompiled)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(_suggBindingList.Add);
    _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
    _suggBindingList.ResetBindings();
    
    _suggLb.Visible = _suggBindingList.Any(); 
    
    if (_suggBindingList.Count == 1 &&  
                _suggBindingList.Single().Length == Text.Trim().Length)
    {
        Text = _suggBindingList.Single();
        Select(0, Text.Length);
        _suggLb.Visible = false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// suggest-ListBox is added to parent control
/// (in ctor parent isn't already assigned)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void OnParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Parent.Controls.Add(_suggLb);
    Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(_suggLb, 0);
    _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3;
    _suggLb.Left = Left + 3;
    _suggLb.Width = Width - 20;
    _suggLb.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9);
}

protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    // _suggLb can only getting focused by clicking (because TabStop is off)
    // --> click-eventhandler 'SuggLbOnClick' is called
    if (!_suggLb.Focused)
        HideSuggBox();
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
}
protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e)
{
base.OnLocationChanged(e);
_suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3;
_suggLb.Left = Left + 3;
}
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
base.OnSizeChanged(e);
_suggLb.Width = Width - 20;
}

private void SuggLbOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Text = _suggLb.Text;
    Focus();
}

private void HideSuggBox()
{
    _suggLb.Visible = false;
}

protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
{
    HideSuggBox();
    base.OnDropDown(e);
}

#region keystroke events

/// <summary>
/// if the suggest-ListBox is visible some keystrokes
/// should behave in a custom way
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_suggLb.Visible)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        return;
    }

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Down:
            if (_suggLb.SelectedIndex < _suggBindingList.Count - 1)
                _suggLb.SelectedIndex++;
            return;
        case Keys.Up:
            if (_suggLb.SelectedIndex > 0)
                _suggLb.SelectedIndex--;
            return;
        case Keys.Enter:
            Text = _suggLb.Text;
        Select(0, Text.Length);
        _suggLb.Visible = false;
            return;
        case Keys.Escape:
            HideSuggBox();
            return;
    }

    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}

private static readonly Keys[] KeysToHandle  = new[] 
            { Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Enter, Keys.Escape };
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // the keysstrokes of our interest should not be processed be base class:
    if (_suggLb.Visible && KeysToHandle.Contains(keyData))
        return true;
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: While this might have solved your issue (whatever it was), it has nothing in common with your question, which title and content are still misleading - a typical XY problem. Thus I don't see how it would help to someone in the future.

Comment: @IvanStoev that is why in my answer I clearly said it is a "work around" which means an alternative to the original issue posted. In other words if they never get the "LIKE clause" to work then they use this as a "work around." I disagree that it has nothing to do with the current question, it does, it is just a "WORK AROUND."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of

```
'%" + comboBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'
```

You meant to use the value of a textbox? Like:

```
'%" + textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'
```

Comment: No the value has to be coming from the comboBox. It is a comboBox that accepts texts based on autocomplete

Comment: FYI @basarab you use the tilda character for formatting in-line code blocks, not single-quote. Additionally, if you're indenting your code with 4 spaces on its own line, it does not need the tilda characters. I've proposed an edit to your post with these changes, but just letting you know for next time.

Comment: Thanks, @sab669. I tried indenting the code section with four spaces, but I can't manage to make it work. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a type for your data
2. Create a list of that type
3. Populate the list with data from your database
4. Sort list using linq extension methods
5. Bind sorted list to combobox

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Configuration;
    namespace Combo
    {
      
      class DataItem
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
      }
      public partial class MainForm : Form
      {
        List<DataItem>dataitems=new List<DataItem>();
        public MainForm()
        {
          
          InitializeComponent();
          textBox1.TextChanged+=textbox1textChanged;
          getDataItems();
          comboBox1.DisplayMember="Name";
          comboBox1.DataSource=dataitems;
            
        }
    
        void textbox1textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
                {
            comboBox1.DataSource=dataitems.FindAll(d => d.Name.StartsWith(textBox1.Text));
                }
        }
        void getDataItems()
            {
                try
                {
                    using (
                        SqlConnection connection =
                            new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataItem"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            string query = @"SELECT p.ProductId,p.ProductName FROM Product p";
                            var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
                            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                              var data=new DataItem();
                              data.Id=reader.GetInt32(0);
                              data.Name=reader.GetString(1);
                              dataitems.Add(data);
                            }
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message.ToString(), "Error");
                }
    
    
            }
      }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  framework 4.0 or upper, then you can try only adding the following line after populate the datasource, that is to say, after filcari() in the constructor.

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

and remove the where clause in your query.

Comment: I do not want an autocomplete. I even said that in my description. Autocomplete only works on the first character entered. I want when I enter any character/characters, whether it be the beginning, end, middle then it still pulls the string I want. For eg. If I have the word "stack123" and then I type "123" or "stack" or "k12" it still pulls the word "stack123". Please take the time to read the original description properly

Answer (score 0):

This sample works to filter the combo items based on the hint text but has an issue when the combobox overwrites the hint with selected text.  It re-populates the combobox each time you type another letter.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PopulateCombo(String.Empty);
}

private void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var hint = comboBox1.Text;
    PopulateCombo(hint);
}

private void PopulateCombo(string hint)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    var connString = @"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=NORTHWND;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using(var con2 = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        var query = "select CategoryName from Categories where CategoryName like '%' + @HINT + '%'";
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2))
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@HINT", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd2.Parameters["@HINT"].Value = hint.Trim();
            con2.Open();
            var dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                 comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2.GetString(0));
            }
            //reset cursor to end of hint text
            comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length;
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
}
```